Accessibility service of specific android device keeps doing malfunctioning and stops working
So, I have made this application which base functionality is dependent upon accessibilty service of android system. Now after the development, I see issue happening that for some specific devices like oneplus or poco, after using some time the app do malfunctioning and the service stops working, unless user has to force stop the application and then run again. I am not being able to debug the issue still, my accessibilty service structure looks like this
onAccessibilityEvent(){}
onServiceConnected(){}
onDestroy() {}

and for the config XML file looks like this
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<accessibility-service xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:accessibilityEventTypes="typeAllMask"

android:accessibilityFeedbackType="feedbackAllMask|feedbackGeneric|feedbackAudible|feedbackHaptic|feedbackSpoken|feedbackVisual"
android:accessibilityFlags="flagDefault|flagReportViewIds|flagIncludeNotImportantViews" android:canPerformGestures="true" android:canRetrieveWindowContent="true" android:description="@string/accessibility_service_description" android:notificationTimeout="100" android:canRequestFilterKeyEvents="true" android:packageNames="@null" />

I also faced the same issue. I resolved it by using WorkManager to restart the service periodically.
Here are some possible solutions
1. Check Battery Optimization Settings
Some devices aggressively kill background services to save battery. Ensure that your application is excluded from battery optimization settings. You can guide users to disable battery optimization for your app programmatically.
2. Foreground Service
Running the accessibility service as a foreground service can prevent it from being killed by the system.
3. Service Restart
Implement a mechanism to restart the service if it is killed. You can use JobScheduler or WorkManager to periodically check if the service is running and restart it if necessary.
